# How to get and set item by localStorage in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, local-storage

I have two webpage with different hostname, the hostname of webpage A is 'a.b.info' and the other is 'c.d.com', for example. Now I want to hybird the webpage B into the webpage A by iframe, that is to say the attribute src of the iframe is 'c.d.com'.I used localStorage in website B, when I open 'a.b.info' in Chrome Incognito Window, the webpage B threw out an exception:

```
DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
```

It will only happen in an Incognito Window in Chrome. please tell me how to deal with this exception?

Comment: Open an issue to Chrome's bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly access properties like localStorage, cookies, or sessionStorage  across domains.

However you can hack around this. You would need to setup some message communication such that webpage A and B can send messages to each other. In those messages, you can include raw string data which can include your localStorage data. ( I don't think it is a very secure thing to do,  specially if you are sharing secrets or some sort of auth data)

Have a look at this example:
https://gist.github.com/pbojinov/8965299